# how to communicate between C# (or C++) and JAVA

Tags: c#, java, jakarta-ee, rfid

i am working on a RFID based project in which we should communicate with Gates(RFID tag reader is called a GATE) through our application (and we are using java 2 ee to do this). the problem is the Gates are only shipping with c# and c++ SDK.
what is your solution to communicate between c++ / C# and java? is there any so called convertor that can ease the pain? 
and this is the Gates manufacturer website if you need any more info : http://www.marktrace.com/en/default.html

thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JNI - Java Native Interface - You can use it to call C++ code from Java.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/

Here is a [tutorial](http://thebreakfastpost.com/2012/01/21/wrapping-a-c-library-with-jni-introduction/).

Comment: thnx - what about c++ or c#?

Comment: @dave - C++ also - have updated my post - it contains a link to a tutorial also.

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for the [Java native interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) which allows you to communicate with other libraries.

You can either call methods from an external DLL and call Java methods from within your C++ code.

You can use [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) to have a bridge to .NET libraries as well.

Comment: jnu4net?i will google it . it seems to be the easiest solution for one week deadline of mine.

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the JNI that the other answers mention, I was writing a similar program for collage and we just wrote a C# client that talked to the library then bridged the gap to java by writing a simple TCP server in C# that the main java app talked to.

Comment: thnx for reply, it seems a bit difficult for one week deadline :)

Answer (score 0):

[Java Native Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is what you need. There are also couple of alternatives and specific libs